# Действие по нажатию определенной клавиши jquery

Tags: jquery

Нужно сделать так чтобы по нажатию клавиши (Enter) вызывалась функция.

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Answer (score 1):

Есть ощущение, что дубликат, но вот решение.

```js
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    //здесь ваша функция
    console.log('enter!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```